# format issue in scala, while having wildcards characters

Tags: scala

I have a sql query suppose

```
sqlQuery="select * from %s_table where event like '%holi%'"
listCity=["Bangalore","Mumbai"]
for (city<- listCity){
   print(s.format(city))
}
```

Expected output:

```
select * from Bangalore_table where event like '%holi%'
select * from Mumbai_table where event like '%holi%'
```

Actual output:

```
unknown format conversion exception: Conversion='%h'
```

Can anyone let me how to solve this, instead of holi it could be anything iam looking for a generic solution in scala.

Comment: There are multiple errors in this code, so please provide working sample code, and try it before you post it. (Online tools like [scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org) make this easy).

Comment: We can use 
s.replace("%s",city)
Got the answer, sorry if i bothered your time. I am new to scala so stumbled on small one

Answer (score 2):

If you want the character `%` in a formatting string you need to escape it by repeating it:

```
sqlQuery = "select * from %s_table where event like '%%holi%%'"
```

More generally I would not recommend using raw SQL. Instead, use a library to access the database. I use Slick but there are a number to choose from.

Also, having different tables named for different cities is really poor database design and will cause endless problems. Create a single table with an indexed `city` column and use `WHERE` to select one or more cities for inclusion in the query.